# Can't install Cookiecutter please?

Tags: cookiecutter

I've tried installing an existing cookiecutter (git@github.com:Dekalabs/cookiecutter-backend.git) both from ubuntu and the windows terminal, and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lisa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\lisa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Lisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\cookiecutter.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\lisa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\lisa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\lisa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\lisa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\lisa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\cli.py", line 152, in main
    skip_if_file_exists=skip_if_file_exists,
  File "c:\users\lisa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\main.py", line 74, in cookiecutter
    directory=directory,
  File "c:\users\lisa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\repository.py", line 114, in determine_repo_dir
    no_input=no_input,
  File "c:\users\lisa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\vcs.py", line 104, in clone
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
  File "c:\users\lisa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "c:\users\lisa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'clone', 'git@github.com:Dekalabs/cookiecutter-backend.git']' returned non-zero exit status 128.
```

I've read through a few other posts with similar errors but can't seem to be able to figure it out. Please advise! :)

Comment: I did exactly as described in https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/installation.html through $ pip install --user cookiecutter . works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by failure of command `git clone`.

A workaround:

You can go to `ithub.com:Dekalabs/cookiecutter-backend.git`, download the whole source package as zip, then extract it, for example, to `/tmp/cookiecutter-backend`.

Then run the following command:

`cookiecutter /tmp/cookiecutter-backend`

For normal python package template, you can just use `ppw` (Python Project Wizard), it's cookiecutter based too, but it has both cookiecutter and template packaged, so you can run it in a easy way:

```
pip install ppw
ppw
```

then follow the instructions to initiate the new project.

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar problem trying run:

```
https://github.com/adafruit/cookiecutter-adafruit-circuitpython.git
```

the process terminates with the following error

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/adafruit/cookiecutter-adafruit-circuitpython.git']' returned non-zero exit status 128.
```

have tried `git config --global http.sslVerify false` but no success

Comment: Mine is working now, although I don't quite recall what I did. I think it had something to do with the SSH keys on GitHub - have you set yours?

Comment: This is not an answer.